# Maths Formula for how sigma.js create view

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, canvas, geometry

I am having very hard time understanding sigmas.js , how it works . Interested to know  science behind the seen .

Reading library I understood that it renders vertices and edges on canvas .

It has an amazing code which resales the coordinate based on number of vertices and edges of graph to show all nodes .

What is maths for calculating view at applyview method https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/classes/sigma.classes.camera.js#L89

**How apply view  works :**

```
sigma.classes.camera.prototype.applyView = function(read, write, options) {
    options = options || {};
    write = write !== undefined ? write : this.prefix;
    read = read !== undefined ? read : this.readPrefix;

    var nodes = options.nodes || this.graph.nodes(),
        edges = options.edges || this.graph.edges();

    var i,
        l,
        node,
        relCos = Math.cos(this.angle) / this.ratio,
        relSin = Math.sin(this.angle) / this.ratio,
        nodeRatio = Math.pow(this.ratio, this.settings('nodesPowRatio')),
        edgeRatio = Math.pow(this.ratio, this.settings('edgesPowRatio')),
        xOffset = (options.width || 0) / 2 - this.x * relCos - this.y * relSin,
        yOffset = (options.height || 0) / 2 - this.y * relCos + this.x * relSin;

    for (i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      node[write + 'x'] =
        (node[read + 'x'] || 0) * relCos +
        (node[read + 'y'] || 0) * relSin +
        xOffset;
      node[write + 'y'] =
        (node[read + 'y'] || 0) * relCos -
        (node[read + 'x'] || 0) * relSin +
        yOffset;
      node[write + 'size'] =
        (node[read + 'size'] || 0) /
        nodeRatio;
    }

    for (i = 0, l = edges.length; i < l; i++) {
      edges[i][write + 'size'] =
        (edges[i][read + 'size'] || 0) /
        edgeRatio;
    }

    return this;
  };
```

Comment: The Plunker does not work for me.I do however not know if it's only me..

Comment: I have posted my plunker code

Comment: Can you help me basically how rescale  method works https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.rescale.js

Comment: In autorescale on , it says center is 0 , 0 . How this coordinate system works . If I have add node and do animation with moving in one direction How to do?@frankenapps

Comment: Updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/vWuE7VctzGWfDae9PyjT?p=preview

Comment: Sigma.js finds the extent of the element's, top,left,right bottom and scales to fit or fill depending on bounding area. Forced layout gives each node a mass and then pushes them apart using negative gravity (inverse square law). The repulsion seems to be from regional mass centers. All child nodes are repulsed from their collective mass center, then each child gets a mass center and their child nodes get repulsed from that, and so on. There is a little math to stop collisions. Nodes are defined as quadrants , topleft, topRight, etc and child nodes added depending on region content.

Comment: In rescale file what is readPrefix   and  writePrefix  conceptually ? Can you explain me whats happing at https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/9c940aa9b162c7aaaf8b25d88e236cb847c1633a/src/middlewares/sigma.middlewares.rescale.js#L139

Comment: Can you explain me whats is relCos  , relSin , nodeRatio  and whats happening at https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/9c940aa9b162c7aaaf8b25d88e236cb847c1633a/src/classes/sigma.classes.camera.js#L89 @Blindman67

Comment: hi @Blindman67 can you help me with question