# Canvas Sin curve drawing

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to create sine curve between -360 ( left most ) to 360 (right most) in canvas .

As like my school days I have created axis x and y and running for loop between -360 to 360 to find y over changing x . But I don't know how to divide Y coordinate value in -1 to 1 range .

1) How to translate coordinate along x and y axis and center in middle as (0,0)

2) How to divide x axis in proportional ratio of 8 blocks between -2pi to +2pi

[JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sumeetpri/xry8jn18/)

[image]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var gap =10;
for(let j=0;j<canvas.height;j=j+gap){
  context.moveTo(0,j);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width,j)
}

for(let j=0;j<canvas.width;j=j+gap){
  context.moveTo(j,0);
  context.lineTo(j,canvas.height);
}


context.strokeStyle= 'green';
context.stroke()

// AXIS

context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth =3;
context.strokeStyle="red";

//X axis
context.moveTo(0,canvas.height/2);
context.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height/2);
//y axis
context.moveTo(canvas.width/2,0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width/2,canvas.height);

context.stroke();


var x = 0;
var y=canvas.height/2;


context.moveTo(x,y);

for(i=-360;i<=360;i=i+10){
  x = i;
   y= (Math.PI/180)*i;
   context.lineTo(x,y);
   context.moveTo(x,y);    
}

context.stroke();
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <html>
  <body>
      <canvas id="my_canvas" width="600px" height="500px"></canvas>
  </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes made to the sine wave graph:

- I just modified the x and y axis to the wave function I wrote to match the origin where the wave begins to generate.
- While generating your sine wave, you need to incremently change the value of the y axis since, you havn't done that you obtained a straight line. I used this expression `y =  180 - Math.sin(counter) * 120;` where counter's value is increasing `(to obtain the value of increase you can literally take any PI/value but we've made use of PI/18 small increments for each coordinate as you can see initialized in the increase variable )`exponentially not linearly and then decreasing again and we have made the for loop run for 2*PI instead of PI to get 2 complete wave instances, one before the origin and one after.
- In addition to it, you need to `move to the x and y values in the loop after you've incremented` to make use of the stroke and connect to the previous coordinates, and not at the beginning.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var gap = 10;
for (let j = 0; j < canvas.height; j = j + gap) {
  context.moveTo(0, j);
  context.lineTo(canvas.width, j)
}

for (let j = 0; j < canvas.width; j = j + gap) {
  context.moveTo(j, 0);
  context.lineTo(j, canvas.height);
}


context.strokeStyle = 'green';
context.stroke()

// AXIS

context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = "red";

//X axis
for (i = 0; i < 720; i += 20) {
  context.lineTo(i, 180);
}
context.stroke();
//y axis
context.moveTo(canvas.width / 2 + 60, 0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2 + 60, canvas.height);
context.stroke();


var counter = 0,
  x = 0,
  y = 180;
context.moveTo(x, y);


var increase = 90 / 180 * Math.PI / 9;
for (i = 0; i <= 720; i = i + 10) {
  x = i;
  y = 180 - Math.sin(counter) * 120;
  counter += increase;
  context.lineTo(x, y);

}
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="600px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Could you explain the solution to Sumeet?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I did.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Cheers :)

Comment: var increase = 90 / 180 * Math.PI / 9;
Can you explain this @Highdef

Comment: @Sumeet (to obtain the value of increase you can literally take any PI/value but we've made use of PI/18 small increments for each coordinate as you can see initialized in the increase variable) as highlighted, if you see that that computes to PI/18, now if you change that value to say 90 / 180 * Math.PI / 3 which is equal to PI/6 you'll have more waves generated compactly, since the counter is making use of this increment, but eitherway our sin wave is conserved, its just a medium to how spacious your wave should be in the x-axis, try to tweak it around.

Comment: I am learning canvas because I am stuck in understanding below post question , can you help how its calculating relative cos and sin as per center  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516597/maths-formula-for-how-sigma-js-create-view

Comment: @Sumeet Oh and one thing to note that these increments, PI/ value, make sure the value divides 180 properly as PI is 180 degrees, and that's how the incrementing coordinates are equally divided, if you have some improper value which doesn't divide PI the graph will mess up.

Comment: @Sumeet Sorry but I havn't done any sigma.js and I don't know what the syntax would exactly refer to. But there are plenty of references you can make use of for learning canvas or anything, but for waves and all, I'd say to brush up some basic trigonometric functionalities as to how their values change or increment. That will help you to understand anything once you understand their syntax as well, because semantics is what matters more.

Comment: In first iteration is not x = -360 which does not exist in canvas , how context.moveTo(x, y) understand I have to start with left most x axis @Highdef

Comment: @Sumeet just use 0 instead of -360.